# Need help locating a Ford Focus part

Tags: ford, part-identification

Found this small cap on the floor inside the cabin of a Ford Focus, need help locating where it belongs. Thank you!

[image: part]

Comment: A search for the part number shows that it is part of an electrical connector.

Comment: @HandyHowie thank you. Any idea where this electrical connector may be?

Comment: Check under both front seats for any electrical boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Look above where the front passenger's feet go. Sometimes they kick up, near the fuse box (which lowers down) and knock bits off. Look especially where the fuse box raises and lowers.